# JSF toggle multiple identical images one at a time

Tags: jsf-2

I have 50+ same images displayed. On-click selected image should change to another one. My problem is, with the following code, click toggles all images and not just the clicked one, because it references the same thing 50+ times. Is there a way of doing this without the need to make different variables for each image? My code:

(This 50 times...):

```
<h:commandLink action="#{bean.imageToggle}">
    <h:graphicImage value="#{bean.img}" />
</h:commandLink>
```

And imgToggle function:

```
public String imageToggle() {
    if (img.equals("resources/images/first.png"))
        img = "resources/images/second.png";
    else
        img = "resources/images/first.png";
    return img;
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason you *need* to use JSF for this? This works perfectly fine with a simple Javascript event handler that changes the `<img src>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try operate img with Object type.
Maybe like this:

**MyImg.class**

```
public class MyImg{
    private String pic1;
    private String pic2;
    private boolean isPic1=true;

    public MyImg(String pic1, String pic2){//Constructor
        this.pic1=pic1;
        this.pic2=pic2;
    }

    public void imageToggle(){//To flag "isPic1"
        isPic1=!isPic1;
    }

    public String getPic(){
        if(isPic1){
            return pic1;
        }else{
            return pic2; 
        }
    }

}
```

And you got 50+ MyImg Objects. I moved your **`imageToggle()`** into `MyImg.class` so that every MyImg Object record and flag their own status.

Of course you need to edit **Page**,too :
**Page:**

```
<p:dataTable var="img" value="#{myBean.myImgs}">    
    <p:column>  
        <h:commandLink action="#{img.imageToggle()}">
            <h:graphicImage value="#{img.pic}" />
        </h:commandLink>
    </p:column>  
</p:dataTable>
```

With `<p:dataTable>` of [Primefaces](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatableBasic.jsf), you don't need to declare so much variables but just simply put your data into a List in your Bean like:

**MyBean:**

```
private List<MyImg> myImgs=new ArrayList<>();

@PostConstruct
public void initializeImgs(){
    myImgs.add(new MyImg("resources/images/first_1.png","resources/images/second_1.png"));
    myImgs.add(new MyImg("resources/images/first_2.png","resources/images/second_2.png"));
...
}

public List<MyImg> getMyImgs(){
    return myImgs;
}
```

Comment: Also, you can use other repeatable components like `ui:repeat` or [`p:dataList`](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/dataListHome.jsf) or [`p:dataGrid`](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datagrid.jsf) or something else instead of `p:dataTable`.